# Replacing error with a zero

Tags: ms-office, office365

I have the following problem.

L8= M8/K8
But,if the sheet vallues are not entered, L8= #DIV/0!
What formula do I need to use if I want L8 to be zero only?

Thanks

Comment: Stil not working - "we found a problem with this formula. Try clicking insert function on the formulas tab to fix it, or click help...."

Comment: Oh yes i am using 2013 version

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible answers depending on your version of Excel.

If you have Excel 2007 or later, you can just do `=IFERROR(M8/K8, 0)`

If you have Excel 2003 or prior you need to do: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(M8/K8)), M8/K8, 0)`

Note: the 2nd option is the same as `=IF(ISERROR(M8/K8), 0, M8/K8)` however it follows a best practice of how to order true/false statements.